# Keyword BOGUS in php

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm wondering what the word "BOGUS" means in the following object.

I'm running a script on the command line, sending a object back over SOAP. I expect back:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["distance"]=>
  string(5) "13726"
  ["time"]=>
  string(3) "622"
}
```

But the first time I ran it, I got this back:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["distance"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["BOGUS"]=>
    string(5) "13726"
  }
  ["time"]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
    ["BOGUS"]=>
    string(3) "622"
  }
}
```

This only happened once, I can't duplicate it. But I'm intrigued and wondering if anyone knows what it means.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"BOGUS" doesn't mean amything to PHP. It would appear to be what was in the response returned by your SOAP request.

Presumably the SOAP server didn't like your input that one time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the soap service is referring to [this bogus](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115725/)

Answer (score -1):

BOGUS in php means nothing.

Most likely someone on the other end was having fun. Probably it's some debugging data that you accidently caught.